# What size should be aimed for when breaking up large data structures for processing? Specifically segment size of sieve

Tags: c++, data-structures, language-agnostic, profiling, cpu-cache

Some large data structures have low locality of reference. This is bad for caching. I am implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes. It contains a long list of numbers. It is possible to process the list in [segments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve) to improve the cache hit ratio. What size should the segment size be? I've [heard](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesieve/wiki/Segmented-sieve-of-Eratosthenes) L1 instruction set cache should work best. Based on my tests a larger size works better, though I'm basically just trying different sizes. Why would sizes larger than the L1 cache actually result in an overall faster execution time? Should the cache size be for a single core or all the cores? Other than CPU cache are there other possible values, like page size?

I know profiling would determine the best size, but I need to know which values to test in the first place.

In the Windows task manager it says the computer has 256KB L1 cache. But in [CPU-Z](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-Z) it says L1 Data is "4x32 Kbytes". In my program the list of numbers is represented by a `std::vector<unsigned char>` Since an `unsigned-char` is ` byte, and I'm guessing Kbytes is actually kibibytes, so the segment size would be 32x1024. Because there's 2^10 bytes in a kibibyte. Is all this correct?

Comment: 256KB is probably 256KBits. 4×32Kbytes - the 4× is due to 4 cores of thr CPU. "Sieve of Eratosthenes" if you are bothered by such nuances - why not implement a faster method for finding primes? There are sublinear methods.

Comment: @ALX23z can you elaborate on any/all of what you're saying? Why would KB mean kbits and not kbytes? Do you know of an implementation of a sieve that runs faster than linear?

Comment: Why KB=KBits? Classical marketing trick. That's how they market internet speed. But this is only speculation - you'd better verify on manufacturers' website.

Comment: "Sieve of Erathostheses" is a specific algorithm for finding primes. Sub linear algorithms for finding primes  are called differently. I once seen one on Wiki - but you'd better checkout articles on this subject. Though, they can never be better than `O(n/log n)` because that's the number of primes up to `n`.